# Filtering Conditions in Python Serializer

Tags: python, django, serialization

I am trying to use a serializer to get all venues within a model that matches a boolean condition in its model. I am trying to get all venues that match the condition is "is Sponsored."  Here is what I have so far:

Model

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    venue_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False)
    venue_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to= ‘venue_photo/', blank=False, default='')
    venue_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to= ‘venue_logo/', blank=False, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    ratings = models.FloatField(default="0.0", blank=True)
    sponsored_venue = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    signup = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    last_signin = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name=‘venue')
```

Serializer

```
class VenueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    venue_logo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    venue_photo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    opening_hours = OpeningHoursSerializer(
        many=True, source='openinghours_set', read_only=True)

# shows these fields from each venue signed up
    def get_venue_logo(self, venue):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        venue_logo_url = venue.venue_logo.url
        if venue_logo_url:
            return request.build_absolute_uri(venue_logo_url)
        return ""
    def get_venue_photo(self, venue):
        request = self.context.get('request')
        venue_photo_url = venue.venue_photo.url
        if venue_photo_url:
            return request.build_absolute_uri(venue_photo_url)
        return ""
    class Meta:
        model = venue
        fields = ("id", "venue_name", "phone", "street_address", "venue_logo", "venue_photo",
                  "street_address", "city", "state", "zip_Code", "lat", "lng", 'latlng', 'opening_hours', "ratings")
```

Comment: And what's the problem do you have?

Comment: I do not know how to get the venues that match the condition is Sponsored = true

Comment: I see only field called `sponsored_venue` - if this the right one, you can simple filter a queryset that passed to serializer `Venue.objects.filter(sponsored_venue=True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Serializer is only responsible for the ***Serialization process of data you provided***. You can control the ***Model QuerySet*** from the place where the serializer is called (probably from the view)

Something like this,

```
qs = Venue.objects.filter(sponsored_venue=True)
serializer = VenueSerializer(qs, many=True)
serialzed_data= serializer.data
```